# Preventing "pasting" (p) from copying selected text to register in Vim

Tags: vim

What I want is:

- Copy some part of text
- Replace some other parts of text with copied part.

What I do is:

- Make a selection: <kbd>v</kbd>
- Yanking the selection: <kbd>y</kbd>
- Making another selection: <kbd>v</kbd>
- Paste the yanked text: <kbd>p</kbd>

But whenever I paste, it replaces current selection with old yanked selection, but copies the replaced (deleted) selection to register. How to make <kbd>p</kbd> just paste and do nothing more?

Comment: I think I could not make it much clear. Sorry for making it hard to understand. If you don't understand the question please ask in comments :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very good answer but...

Instead of selecting and pasting (<kbd>p</kbd>):

- move to beginning of selection to be replaced
- paste
- select unwanted selection
- delete it using "delete to black-hole register" (<kbd>"_d</kbd>)

or vice versa, "delete to black-hole register", then paste.

Comment: I would love to see better answers. Cause this answer is quite not satisfying for me. >_<